# Error when using EXCEPT on my SELECT statement

Tags: sql, mariadb

```
SELECT *
FROM product
LEFT JOIN `product_tag_link` ON `product`.`productid`             = `product_tag_link`.`productid`
LEFT JOIN `product_tag`      ON `product_tag_link`.`producttagid` = `product_tag`.`producttagid`
WHERE `product_tag`.`producttagid` = 1

EXCEPT

SELECT pol.groupid, pol.productid, p.title, p.packageid, po.groupname
FROM `product_onetime_list` pol
LEFT JOIN `product` p ON pol.productid = p.productid
LEFT JOIN `product_onetime` po ON pol.groupid = po.groupid
WHERE pol.groupid = 1
```

Trying to get the rows of this SQL but I am getting an issue on EXCEPT

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'EXCEPT
>   SELECT pol.groupid, pol.productid, p.title, p.packageid, po.groupnam' at line 6

Comment: What version of the DB are you using? I think EXCEPT was only introduced in version 10.3 (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/except/). If you're on a later version, maybe check that the '*' in your first statement is returning an identical set of columns to your second statement.

Answer (score 0):

For Expect Columns two Selects In sql should **Similar to each other**.And **Instead o**f * write down the **full columns name** .

The following **example** uses the **EXCEPT** operator :

```
SELECT
    product_id FROM
    production.products EXCEPT 
SELECT
    product_id FROM
    sales.order_items;
```

[Help Link](http://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-except/)